# Проблема с запросом cURL на продакшн сервере

Tags: php, curl

У меня есть `PHP` код. Запрос `CURL` проблематичен.
Запрос с локального сервера работает, а с рабочего сервера нет. Вот пример моего запроса. Версия `PHP` И `CURL` на сервере соответственно `5.6.30` и `7.36.0`.

```
$action_url = "https://mysite.am:1234/rest/register.do";
$args = array(
     'userName' => 'test_name',
     'password' => 'test_pass',
     'orderNumber' => '10_7',
     'amount' => 100,
     'returnUrl' => 'returnurl',
 );

$cl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt_array($cl, array(
       CURLOPT_URL => $action_url,
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
       CURLOPT_POST => true,
       CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,                 
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($args, '', '&')
    ));
       $result = curl_exec($cl);
       $info = curl_getinfo($cl);
       $error = curl_error($cl);
       curl_close($cl);
       echo $result;
       echo $error;
       echo print_r($info,true);
```

А вот и результат на рабочем сервере:

```
Curl Error: Failed to connect to mysite.am port 1234: Connection refused
```

Это информация запроса `CURL`:

```
Info: Array
(
    [url] => https://mysite.am:1234/rest/register.do
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.324749
    [namelookup_time] => 0.12451
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
)
```

На локале и в реальном сервере различия:

```
1) localhost - http, real server - https
2) localhost - domain1, real server - domain2
```

И прошу если не знаете чем помочь хоть не мешаете своими комментариями.

Comment: @JohnSmitConor вы читали полностью мой вопрос? на реальном домене на `https` один и тот же запрос не получает ответ, а на локальном тот же запрос нормально работает.

Comment: На локали и на сервере настройки HTTPS (SSL) совпадают? Порт 1234 открыт и там и там?\

Comment: @DNS нет на локале нету `https`

Comment: В этом возможна проблемма. Если на локали есть алтернатива обычного и секретного НТТР, то на настоящем сервере такие альтернативы не приветствуются... Проверьте настройки и процедуры обращения к С-протоколу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попрбуйте убрать CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true и проверьте какая версия php используется. Уcтановите версию не ниже php 5.6

Comment: Это то же пробивал, и в обеих случаях `PHP 5.6`